# Can you list data from two identical tables, one after the other in a select statement?

Tags: mysql, select

I have two tables, that have been structured identically but one is a log of older data and one tracks newer data entries. They are the same structure but the data entries are different (one is data before date x, one is data after date x).

My question is, is there a select statement (using MySQL) that can select all the data from both tables and list it as though it is one table? Essentially just listing the contents from table A, then listing the contents from table B in the same columns as though they are one table.

I could create another table that does this, but that would involve doubling the data size which isn't a scalable solution.

Thanks for any time you take on this!

Comment: See UNION. Then see partitioning. More generally, see the manual.

Comment: two identical tables - that's wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

[Union](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html)

Ex: `SELECT * FROM LOG UNION SELECT * FROM LOG_OLD;`